# Bottom sheet behind navigation bar

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile

I have a screen with a bottom navigation bar and a floating action button.

I'm trying to display a bottom sheet that comes up from behind the bottom navigation bar. Also, I would like to see the barrier. Only the bottom navigation bar and the bottom sheet should be clearly visible, while the rest of the screen must be darkened. (kind of [this](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/6615247/93877814-afcfb180-fcf6-11ea-9324-ba2d30d21c49.png)).

For navigation, I'm using `GetX`, so first I tried to specify `useRootNavigator: true` to `Get.bottomSheet`, but didn't work.

I've seen many answers which suggest the use of `showModalBottomSheet` with `useRootNavigator: true`. Again, didn't work.

I've already achieved this with a custom solution (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73509238/8640235)), but I want to understand what can inhibit the effect of `useRootNavigator` or if there is another built-in solution to achieve my goal.

LE:
I'm doing simple calls, nothing fancy.
References to the documentation below.

GetX package: https://pub.dev/packages/get
[showModalBottomSheet](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html)

Source code example:
https://gist.github.com/alexgrusu/8fd173e56d4046cdbda487e4b98bd950

Comment: Post your code segment for better understanding of problem statement

Comment: @Prashant, I've already provided all details in the description.

The first one implies GetX 
https://pub.dev/packages/get.

The second one implies showModalBottomSheet https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showModalBottomSheet.html

These are simple calls, nothing fancy. If you know these approaches you can answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for this behavior can be achieved through nested navigation.

First, define the keys of the navigators.

```
class NavigatorKeys {
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> mainNavigatorKey = GlobalKey();
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> secondaryNavigatorKey =
      GlobalKey();
}
```

The main key can be assigned to the `navigatorKey` of the `MaterialApp`.

Next, let's consider that our app's home is the dashboard screen so that our `MaterialApp` would look like so.

```
MaterialApp(
   title: 'Demo App',
   home: const DashboardScreen(),
   navigatorKey: NavigatorKeys.mainNavigatorKey,
);
```

Then, the build method for the `DashboardScreen` can be implemented as shown below.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Navigator(
        key: NavigatorKeys.secondaryNavigatorKey,
        onGenerateRoute: (routeSettings) {
          return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) =>
                  _buildMainUi(),
                );
              },
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: _buildNavigationBar(),
    );
  }

  _buildMainUi() => Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text('Dashboard')));
```

In the end, simply pass the context of the secondary navigator to the `showModalBottomSheet` method and set `useRootNavigator` to `false`.

```
  showModalBottomSheet<Widget?>(
      useRootNavigator: false,
      context: NavigatorKeys.secondaryNavigatorKey.currentContext!,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Container(height: 200, child: Text('hello'));
      },
    );
```